# All pairs (x,y) that satisfy the equation $xy+(x^3+y^3)/3=2007$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How we can find the all pairs $(x,y)$  from the integers numbers ,that satisfy the equation :

$$xy+\frac{x^3+y^3}{3} =2007$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the factorization of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$? (This is not a terribly well-known factorization.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, are you saying $x^3+y^3+(-1)^3-3xy(-1)=(x+y-1)(x^2+y^2+1-xy+x+y)$? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan can  you elaborate a bit more , please ?

Answer (score 7):

Observe that the equation is symmetric.

As $3\mid(x^3+y^3)$, either $(x,y)$ will be $(3a+1,3b-1)$,  $(3a-1,3b+1)$ or $(3a,3b)$.

If $(x,y)$ is $(3a+1,3b-1)$, $\frac{x^3+y^3}{3}=3(3a^3+3b^3+3a^2-3b^2+a+b)$

So, $3$ must divide $xy$ which is impossible as $xy=(3a+1)(3b-1)$

So,  $(x,y)$ will be  $(3a,3b)$.

So,$9(ab+a^3+b^3)=2007\implies a^3+b^3+ab=223$

Now, $223$ is prime, so, $(a,b)=1$

If we think of solution in natural number, $a<7$ .

By trial (which is aided by $(a,b)=1$), $(a,b)$ is $(6,1)$ or $(1,6)$.

Comment: The question specifies integers, not just natural numbers.   However, it is not hard to see that at least one of $a,b$ must be positive.  If $a > 0 > b$ then $a^3 + b^3 + ab$ takes its least positive value when $|b|=a-1$.  This still constrains $a$ to be less than $12$.

Comment: @ErickWong, thanks for your instructive feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x+y=a,xy=b$ then the equation is equivalent to $$a^3-3abc+3b=6021$$ or $$(a-1)(a^2+a+1-3b)=6020$$
Now it is easy to do.

Comment: can  you elaborate a bit more  please ?

Comment: use modular arithmatic

Answer (score 1):

Note that the given equation is $$x^3+y^3+3xy=6021$$ or $$x^3+y^3-1+3xy=6020$$
Factoring it we get , $$(x+y-1)(x^2+y^2+1+x+y-xy)=2^2.5.7.43$$
Obviously check $\equiv 3$ and see $$x+y-1\equiv 2 \mod 3$$ 
Also, $$x+y-1 < x^2+y^2+1+x+y-xy$$ 
This means, $$x+y-1 \rightarrow 20,5,2,35$$ 
so now it's easy to see that $$x+y-1=20$$ and so $(x, y)=(18,3)$ or $(3,18)$